# Can't listen 'popstate' event in Chrome 77?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Need to listen 'Back button' in Chrome 77. I know that for this using 'popstate' event listenter.
I tried:

```
window.onpopstate = function (event) {
    console.log("location: " + document.location + ", state: " + JSON.stringify(event.state));
};

window.addEventListener('popstate', (event) => {
    console.log("location: " + document.location + ", state: " + JSON.stringify(event.state));
});
```

Nothing working. Tried also with debugging... 
How to investigate this event and why it's happened (worked before)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my last experience:

popstate event only works when there is an user interaction on the page.

For example:

click anywhere on the screen then hit back button. You will get popstate fired . Put an alert to feel it easily.

For more detail, please refer: https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2019/05/09/chrome-plans-to-save-you-from-sites-that-mess-with-your-back-button/