# how to alert users that changes are not saved

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to alert users before leaving the page - if button `bsave` is visible - that changes are not saved.

Nothing works (Chrome, other browsers are not tested).

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    if($('#bsave').is(':visible')){
        alert('CHANGES ARE NOT SAVED !');
        return; // should prevent closing the window
    }
});
```

Also tried the following - without success

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
var c=confirm();
if(c){
  return true;
}
else
return false;
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead using `alert` method, just return your message. Browsers will automatically create an alert for that:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
   if ($('#bsave').is(':visible')){
        return 'CHANGES ARE NOT SAVED !';
   }
}
```

Comment: doesn't work. Click on `x` - close the tab without alert.

Comment: ohh I see, so your problem is same as I answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58274613/cant-listen-popstate-event-in-chrome-77/58275308#58275308 . You cannot enforce an event without user interaction. click on page anywhere and then click 'x', same code will work. So leaving unsaved changes test is only possible when there is a real user interaction not just reloading and closing the tab.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event):

> To combat unwanted pop-ups, browsers may not display prompts created in `beforeunload` event handlers unless the page has been interacted with, or may even not display them at all.

The `beforeunload` function should return a string if you want it to provide a response to the user if they're leaving a page:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    if($('#bsave').is(':visible')){
        return 'CHANGES ARE NOT SAVED !'; // should prevent closing the window
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add paranthese only, it is working properly.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
var c=confirm();
if(c){
  return true;
}
else
return false;
});
```